# Getting BehaviorSubject with ngIf Direct Access or Subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular, what is the downside of accessing a BehaviorSubject's getValue() directly, versus using a subscription and updating a (local?) variable, for use in *ngIf?

In a shared service:

`currentState : BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);`

In the UI .ts file that uses the shared service:

`constructor (public myservice : SharedService) { };`

In the UI .html file, only show after the service is initialized: (things within it get a null reference for currentState if I don't do this:

`*ngIf="myservice.currentState.getValue() != null"`

OR, subscribe, update a local variable, and use that instead of myservice.getValue(). I'm sure someone is going to ask, why even use a BehaviorSubject if I'm going to do that, but perhaps its so if someone wants to get notice when the service's value changes, they can. Kinda a "event-based-is-available-with-this-service-if-you-want", but also "just-access-it-yourself-if-you-want" based on the use-case of the current UI?

Am I doing this wrong? I'm using the value of the behaviorsubject to control the UI, so I need to use ngIf.

Comment: Both are bad practice. Use the `| async` pipe instead.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Sorry let me clarify, what part of the problem does | async solve for me, is a better question from me to you - the null reference problem?

Comment: I answered with an example on that. I'll add an explanation on why that is better in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution using `async` pipe

Both practices are not optimal. It is considered a best practice to use the `async` pipe with Observables that control the UI. Also, you can use this to leverage Observables even more and make your code more readable by piping into a new Observable which can be named.

On your TS:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
   public displayWhatever$:Observable<boolean> = this.myService.currentState.pipe(
      map(state => !!state) // this is the same as != null, if you really want only "not null" use "state !== null"
   );

   constructor(private myService:SharedService){}
}
```

On your Tempate:

```
<div *ngIf="displayWhatever$ | async"></div>

<!-- If you need to use your state inside your div you can even use some syntax sugar: -->

<div *ngIf="myService.currentState | async as currentState>
   <!-- Use currentState in here as if it was a normal variable -->
</div>
```

#### Why is this better?

The `async` pipe handles subscribing to your Observable as well as unsubscribing for you. Additionally, it triggers the components change detection as needed. This is usually of a concern when the observable can be changed elsewhere and your component is set to `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. It is basically the same as running `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` whenever the observables emits - which is what you want since you might not know where the observables is changed.

Comment: I should be able to use this even with a structure instead of string or boolean right? Like currentState.showOkButton and still enjoy the protection from null on currentState?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. `map(state => !!state)` maps your state to a boolean value which is `true` when your state has a "truthy" value (not: `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""` (empty string), `false`, `NaN` and maybe something I forgot, so a broad check).

Comment: @DanChase Added another example on the template part (if you want to leave out the intermediary observable)